# Docker Scrapy spider save data to Postgres port error

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, scrapy, port

I'm trying to use my scrapy spider to run on a VPS server. So I used Docker image and attached it with PostgreSQL, Scrapy, scrapy-splash images. When I launch the spider with `docker-compose up` I encountered an error with the port and the spider doesn't seem to recognize `self.cur` in my pipelines.py.

When I run the spider on my local pc it ran fine without encounter port or any error in the pipelines.py.

Error on VPS server:

```
2018-08-08 02:19:10 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider midd                                                                                        lewares:
web_1        | ['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
web_1        |  'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware',
web_1        |  'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
web_1        |  'tutorial.middlewares.TutorialSpiderMiddleware',
web_1        |  'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
web_1        |  'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
web_1        |  'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
web_1        | 2018-08-08 02:19:10 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipeli                                                                                        nes:
web_1        | ['tutorial.pipelines.TutorialPipeline']
web_1        | 2018-08-08 02:19:10 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
web_1        | 2018-08-08 02:19:10 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (sh                                                                                        utdown)
web_1        | 2018-08-08 02:19:10 [scrapy.core.engine] ERROR: Scraper close fai                                                                                        lure
web_1        | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py"                                                                                        , line 82, in crawl
web_1        |     yield self.engine.open_spider(self.spider, start_requests)
web_1        | psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connectio                                                                                        n refused
web_1        |  Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accept                                                                                        ing
web_1        |  TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
web_1        | could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
web_1        |  Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
web_1        |  TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
web_1        |
web_1        |
web_1        | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurre                                                                                        d:
web_1        |
web_1        | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/d                                                                                        efer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
web_1        |     current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
web_1        |   File "/scrapy_estate/tutorial/pipelines.py", line 19, in cl                                                                                        ose_spider
web_1        |     self.cur.close()
web_1        | AttributeError: 'TutorialPipeline' object has no attribute 'cur'
web_1        | 2018-08-08 02:19:10 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy                                                                                         stats:
web_1        | {'finish_reason': 'shutdown',
web_1        |  'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 8, 2, 19, 10, 744998),
web_1        |  'log_count/ERROR': 1,
web_1        |  'log_count/INFO': 6}
web_1        | 2018-08-08 02:19:10 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (shu                                                                                        tdown)
web_1        | Unhandled error in Deferred:
web_1        | 2018-08-08 02:19:10 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferr                                                                                        ed:
web_1        |
web_1        | 2018-08-08 02:19:10 [twisted] CRITICAL:
web_1        | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/d                                                                                        efer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
web_1        |     result = g.send(result)
web_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py"                                                                                        , line 82, in crawl
web_1        |     yield self.engine.open_spider(self.spider, start_requests)
web_1        | psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connectio                                                                                        n refused
web_1        |  Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accept                                                                                        ing
web_1        |  TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
web_1        | could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
web_1        |  Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
web_1        |  TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

My Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
FROM python:3.6-onbuild
RUN  apt-get update &&apt-get upgrade -y&& apt-get install python-pip -y && pip3 install psycopg2 && pip3 install psycopg2-binary
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install scrapy --upgrade
run pip3 install scrapy-splash
COPY . /scrapy_estate
WORKDIR /scrapy_estate
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 5432/tcp
CMD scrapy crawl estate
```

Docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  interface:
    links:
      - postgres:postgres
    image: adminer
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - webnet
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: 'postgres'
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: '123'
    volumes:
    - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    networks:
      - webnet

  web:
    image: user/scrapy_estate:latest
    build: ./tutorial
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    networks:
      - webnet
    environment:
      DB_HOST: postgres
    networks:
      - webnet
  splash:
    image: scrapinghub/splash
    ports:
     - "8050:8050"
    expose:
     - "8050"
networks:
  webnet:
```

My pipelines.py

```
import psycopg2
class TutorialPipeline(object):
    def open_spider(self, spider):
        hostname = 'localhost'
        username = 'postgres'
        password = '123' # your password
        database = 'real_estate'
        self.connection = psycopg2.connect(host=hostname, user=username, password=password, dbname=database)
        self.cur = self.connection.cursor()

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.cur.close()
        self.connection.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.cur.execute("insert into estate(estate_title,estate_address,estate_area,estate_description,estate_price,estate_type,estate_tag,estate_date,estate_seller_name,estate_seller_address,estate_seller_phone,estate_seller_mobile,estate_seller_email) values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",(item['estate_title'],item['estate_address'],item['estate_area'],item['estate_description'],item['estate_price'],item['estate_type'],item['estate_tag'],item['estate_date'],item['estate_seller_name'],item['estate_seller_address'],item['estate_seller_phone'],item['estate_seller_mobile'],item['estate_seller_email']))
        self.connection.commit()
        return item
```

### Edit

The spider now worked because I didn't expose port 5432 in docker-compose and there already a postgreSQL installed on my VPS so the port already in used so I killed port 5432 on the VPS, run it again and worked.

Comment: scrapy spider container , postgre container ,  scrapy-splash container  are on the same server ?

Comment: yes i think i created the docker-compose and dockerfile on the VPS server and then build it on the server and trying to run my spider with docker-compose up on it

Comment: I didnot see on `postgres` container it didnot expose port 5432 to outside ?

Comment: you run on local PC , scrapy spider container , postgre container , scrapy-splash container are working fine ?

Comment: when i run on my local pc it wasn't a docker container . I just make the docker files requirement so i can run on the VPS server

Comment: i added expose 5432 in the Dockerfile and build it again , the port error still remain

Comment: please re-check my answer and run again.

Comment: `ports` and `expose`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of ip address gateway of container is  : `172.17.0.1`

So you should change `hostname = 'localhost'` to `hostname = '172.17.0.1'` in pipelines.py file. and run again.

Add port into dockerfile for postgres container:

```
postgres:
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: 'postgres'
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: '123'
    volumes:
    - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    ports:
    - "5432:5432"
    expose:
    - "5432"
    networks:
      - webnet
```

Comment: i changed it in pipelines.py and still return with the same error

Comment: you run on local PC , scrapy spider container , postgre container , scrapy-splash container are working fine ?

Comment: Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5432: bind: address already in use
.Oh wait i think my VPS server already had postgreSQL already installed(probally my work mate installed it on it) that why the 5432 port is blocked

Comment: yup, please stop that service on VPS server, if not it will be duplicated port and cannot start docker container postgres

Comment: yes i just fuser -k 5432/tcp and now the docker-compose up spider worked.Thank you